# CakePHP saveAll() method only saving the last element of the passed array

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm attempting to perform a saveAll in CakePHP but for some reason only the last element of the array is being saved.  Here is the code I'm using the generate the array and save it:

```
        if(isset($article['id'])){
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Google',
                    'num_of_instances' => $google);
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Facebook',
                    'num_of_instances' => $facebook);
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Twitter',
                    'num_of_instances' => $twitter);
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Reddit',
                    'num_of_instances' => $reddit);
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Stumbleupon',
                    'num_of_instances' => $stumbleupon);
            $data[] = array(
                    'article_id' => $article['id'],
                    'name_of_social_site' => 'Digg',
                    'num_of_instances' => $digg);
            debug($data);
            $this->saveAll($data);
```

I've debugged the array to ensure that the it is properly structured.  Here are the debug results:

```
Array
```

(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [article_id] => 86503
            [name_of_social_site] => Google
            [num_of_instances] => 1
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [article_id] => 86503
        [name_of_social_site] => Facebook
        [num_of_instances] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [article_id] => 86503
        [name_of_social_site] => Twitter
        [num_of_instances] => 11
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [article_id] => 86503
        [name_of_social_site] => Reddit
        [num_of_instances] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [article_id] => 86503
        [name_of_social_site] => Stumbleupon
        [num_of_instances] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [article_id] => 86503
        [name_of_social_site] => Digg
        [num_of_instances] =>  0
    )
```

)

The only data saving to the database is the data in the element 5 of the array.  I also tried to user a save method for each individual elemnt in the array but it would still only save the last one.  I'm kind of at a loss here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looping over your array while saving?

Comment: It should be `$this->Model->saveAll($data);`.  Try that and get back with us. (obviously replacing "Model" with your singular/uppercase model)

Comment: The array is built and saved within one iteration of the loop.  It doesn't loop while the data is being saved or created.  The statement is within the model.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I had recently revised my table and code.  I had changed the primary key within the table but I hadn't removed the code public $primaryKey = article_id so it wasn't allowing duplicate article_id's.  Needless to say, I deserve a facepalm.

Comment: no worries - we have all done things like that...

Comment: @TrevorBoland Glad to hear you got it worked out.  If you post your fix as the answer, and then accept it, this question will disappear from the "Unanswered" list.